# Regex for finding sentences within text c#

Tags: c#, regex

The text is in Hebrew, and contains email addresses within the sentences (meaning that the char '.' may indicate not only an end of a sentence but also an email address) I want to split the text into sentences. How can I do it? With what regex pattern?

Comment: Maybe a split on <dot><space>?

Comment: As stated, your question is an "[XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/286722)". Please consider if your solution must truly be in the form of a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Like so: `((([^\.]|\.\S)+[\.\!\?])\s+)`

Each capture at the top level will be a sentence on the assumption that a period followed by a non-space character is part of an email.